# Seeing error: Could not set the list property. Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am seeing the error `Could not set the list property. Type mismatch` when I run the following code.

It works correctly with `For i = 1 To 10` but if I change it to `10 to 100` I see the error.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim myString
Sheets("Welcome").Select
Range("W3").Select
myString = Range("W3")
UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = myString
Sheets("Welcome").Select
Range("AA4").Select
myString = Range("AA4")
UserForm1.TextBox2.Text = myString
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Set ws = Worksheets("August")
Set rng = ws.Range("G2:AK2")
Set fnd = rng.Find(TextBox1)
    If fnd Is Nothing Then MsgBox TextBox1 & " not found": Exit Sub
Set first = fnd
    With ListBox1
    .Clear
        For i = 1 To 100
            .AddItem Worksheets("August").Range("B" & i + 5).Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = fnd.Offset(i + 3, 0)
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: first and foremost, [avoid select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Secondly, work on your indenting.

Comment: Well, what line are you getting the error on?

Comment: .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = fnd.Offset(i + 3, 0)

Comment: looks like you're trying to set `.list =  fnd.offset(4).resize(100).value`.  Makes it so you don't even need the loop

Comment: It looks like you try to set variables that you haven't declared, namely, `fnd` and `first`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested the code below with some random numbers for a data sample and it worked just fine.  Some things to keep in mind while writing your code, as commented above, indenting helps tremendously.  Secondly, I strongly recommend always using `Option Explicit` as the first line in any code module.  This prevents you from using undeclared variables (ie. misspelled).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim fnd As Range                                    <=== Defined as a Range
        UserForm1.TextBox1 = Sheets("Welcome").Range("W3")
        UserForm1.TextBox2 = Sheets("Welcome").Range("AA4")
        Set ws = Worksheets("August")
        Set rng = ws.Range("G2:AK2")
        Set fnd = rng.Find(TextBox1)
        If fnd Is Nothing Then MsgBox TextBox1 & " not found": Exit Sub
        With ListBox1
            .Clear
            For i = 1 To 100
                .AddItem Worksheets("August").Range("B" & i + 5).Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = fnd.Offset(i + 3, 0)
            Next i
        End With
End Sub
```

In the above code, note that I have shortened up the code used to set the value of the text boxes.  Your original code:

```
Dim myString


Sheets("Welcome").Select
Range("W3").Select
myString = Range("W3")

UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = myString

Sheets("Welcome").Select
Range("AA4").Select
myString = Range("AA4")

UserForm1.TextBox2.Text = myString
```

became

```
UserForm1.TextBox1 = Sheets("Welcome").Range("W3")
UserForm1.TextBox2 = Sheets("Welcome").Range("AA4")
```

This is much cleaner.  This works without the `.Text` on the end of `TextBox1` because the `.Text` is the default property.  Also note that I directly referenced the cell with the string that I wanted without "Selecting" it.  Selecting the cell is not necessary to work with it, selecting the cell is only required by a user operating a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, This worked I had a few errors in cells that I didn't notice(#N?A) in some cells

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim fnd As Range
    UserForm1.TextBox1 = Sheets("Welcome").Range("W3")
    UserForm1.TextBox2 = Sheets("Welcome").Range("Z3")
    UserForm1.TextBox3 = Sheets("Welcome").Range("Y3")
    Set ws = Worksheets(TextBox3.Value)
    Set rng = ws.Range("G2:AK2")
    Set fnd = rng.Find(TextBox1)
    If fnd Is Nothing Then MsgBox TextBox1 & " not found": Exit Sub
    With ListBox1
        .Clear
        For i = 1 To 200
            .AddItem Worksheets(TextBox3.Value).Range("B" & i + 5).Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = fnd.Offset(i + 3, 0)
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = Worksheets(TextBox3.Value).Range("E" & i + 5).Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = Worksheets(TextBox3.Value).Range("F" & i + 5).Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = "Oncall"
        Next i
    End With
```